# How to make Filter system in DSS

Tags: php, sql

**This is my hotel.php**
i need to make filter system to display according to filter . For example select price i need to display item within the range option given .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  PHP
</head>

<body>
  <form action="hotelprocess.php" method="POST">
    <p>
      <select name="Photel">
            <option>Select-Price-</option>
            <option value="price">100-300</option>
            <option value="price">301-500</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="hotel" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**This is my hotelprocess.php**
In this file i want make it to display item from database according the the filter system  . I used if below to make sure can display the message but it fail . It has error that say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$prc' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\hotelprocess.php on line 4

```html
<?php
include 'dbh.php'
//Get value pass from form in hotel.php file
$prc = $_POST["prc"];

$prc = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

//DB
$query = "SELECT h_price, n_hotel FROM hotel";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row['prc'] > 0)
{
    echo "hello";
}
else{
    echo "failed to display";
}

?>
```

**This is connetion to database**

```html
<?php
//connect with database
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "register");
if(!$conn){
    die("connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

I hope you guys understand what i ask and sorry for my english .

Comment: *"on line 4"* - Don't believe everything PHP says; it's not always on *that* line.

Comment: You also can't mix different mysql apis.